# Passing arguments for external functions in x86-64 NASM

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, nasm

In x86-32 you `push` arguments to stack, and in x86-64 it also uses some specific registers and only after it the stack. That said, I don't understand why I get `Segmentation fault` while trying to print an integer (`k` and `a` are unused):

```
    global _main
    extern _printf
    section .data
format:  db "%d"
b:  dw 10
blen: equ $-b
lenlen: equ $-blen
k:  dw 6
    section .bss
a:  resw 1
    section .text
_main:
    sub rsp, 8
    mov rax, 0
    mov rdi, format
    mov rsi, b
    call _printf
    mov rax, 0x2000001
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Comment: You also forgot to set `rdi` and `rax`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thanks, now it works, but prints `8210` instead of `10`. Probably it has to do something with addresses (though it prints `8210` all the time, it doesn't change), but I don't understand why I can't use `lea` here (`lea rsi, [b]` gets me `Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses`). Also I have set the `rdi` and `rax`, I forgot to update the question.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica also could you explain why people declare variables like  `msg: db "Hello World!", 10, 0`? I don't understand what `10` and `0` are for, I couldn't find information about it. Maybe it's connected.

Comment: `10` means `\n` and `0` is the NUL-terminator

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica when I change `format` from `"%d"`, which prints `8210`, to `"%d", 10, 0` it prints `8212`, and when I change it to `"%d", 0`, it prints nothing. Why?

Comment: For printing nothing, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/24093313/7509065

Comment: As for the wrong number, `printf` wants a value for %d, not an address, so do `[b]` instead of `b`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica when I change `mov rsi, b` to `mov rsi, [b]` it again says that `error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses`.

Comment: Put `default rel` at the top of your program.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica now it prints some address, and when I change `mov rsi, [b]` to `lea rsi, [b]` (which is probably equivalent to `mov rsi, b`), it prints `8212` again. So it's not about addresses, `8212` is an actual value it finds at `b`. Maybe it has to do something with numeral systems (hex/dex)?

Comment: `dw` means 16-bit but `%d` means 32-bit. Either use `dd` instead of `dw`, or `%hd` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I think I start to lose my sanity. When I change `%d` to `%hd` it prints `8213`, and when I change it back to `%d` and declare `b` as `dd`, it prints `8212` again.

Comment: At this point, I'm afraid your code is too far gone from your original question for me to follow along. You should post a new question with your new problem.

Comment: stdout is line buffered.  With a raw `_exit` syscall, you can exit without giving stdio a change to flush buffers after a printf that didn't end with a newline.  [Using printf in assembly leads to an empty ouput](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38379553).  Don't do that; if you call printf, exit by calling exit(3) from libc.  (or if you were writing a main instead of _start, returning from `main`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, printf needs 2 parameters, a pointer to a format string (rdi), and the value (rsi).

---

That might need to be:

```
default  rel                   ; make [format] be [rel format] by default
format  db      "%d", 0        ;the 0 terminates the C string

;       ...
        lea     rdi, [rel format]  ; put format address in first arg reg
        movsx   esi, word [b]      ; load a value from b, not its address
```

You only defined one word with value 10, so sign-extend it to dword with `movsx` (or zero-extend with movzx) to get a 32-bit int to match the %d format string.

If you'd *wanted* to print a pointer with `mov rsi, b` for the absolute address, you'd use `"%p", 0`

Comment: So I should place in `rdi` `"%s"`?

Comment: https://www.paste.org/106489 — still doesn't work. With `"%d"` too.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica are there any alternatives for macOS? I have found only MASM.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica oh wait, actually it's NASM. I'm using NASM. MASM is for Windows.

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky - I updated my answer.